# In Vue, how to cancel a checkbox based on a condition?

Tags: checkbox, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I want to always have at least one checkbox checked but I mix the concepts of `v-model` and `:checked`.

The [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) says:

> `v-model` will ignore the initial `value`, `checked` or `selected` attributes
> found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data
> as the source of truth.

I can prevent my model to be modified but I can't prevent the checkbox to be checked...

Some code:

*The template*

```
<div class="wrapper" v-for="(s, id) in userOutputSeries" :key="id">
  <input type="checkbox" :id="id" :value="id" @change="preventIfLessThanOneChecked" :checked="s.active">
  <label :for="id">{{ s.display }}</label>
</div>
```

*The model `userOutputSeries`*

```
data () {
  return {
    userOutputSeries: {
      foo: {
        display: 'Awesome Foo',
        active: true
      },
      bar: {
        display: 'My Bar',
        active: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*The `preventIfLessThanOneChecked` handler*

```
preventIfLessThanOneChecked (event) {
  // I don't update the model so it stay at the same state
  // But only need to count the active series and do what we want.
  console.log(event.target.value, event.target.checked)
}
```

Any ideas to stop the native checkbox propagation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `v-model` instead of `:checked` so that changes to the `userOutputSeries` data property will be reflected in the checkbox input.

Then, pass the `s` reference from the `v-for` to the method and set that object's `active` property to `true` if there are no `active` checkboxes:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      userOutputSeries: {
        foo: {
          display: 'Awesome Foo',
          active: true
        },
        bar: {
          display: 'My Bar',
          active: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    preventIfLessThanOneChecked(item) {
      if (item.active) {
        return;
      }
    
      let items = Object.values(this.userOutputSeries);
      if (!items.find(i => i.active)) {
        item.active = true;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper" v-for="(s, id) in userOutputSeries" :key="id">
    <input type="checkbox" :id="id" :value="id" @change="preventIfLessThanOneChecked(s)" v-model="s.active">
    <label :for="id">{{ s.display }}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was stuck with preventing the event instead of thinking of the data... Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

In the above answer given by @thanksd, my checkbox remains unchecked.
So i am writing my solution.

This my loop statement, change the variable names according to your file.

```
v-for="column in tableColumns"
```

This is my input ( if visible is true then checkbox is checked )

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="column.visible" @change="event => visibleColumnsChanged(column, event)">
```

Then in my change method 
 - if there is no visible item left set the column.visible to true
 - use event.target.checked = true to check the checkbox again.

```
visibleColumnsChanged: function(column, event){
  if (column.visible) {
    return;
  }

  if(! this.tableColumns.find(c => c.visible)){
    column.visible = true;

    event.target.checked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tnx much, this should be accepted answer, since when doing un-check, but then changing v-model value pragmatically back to "true" , checkbox will ignore this and remain un-checked even thought model is actually true. This kind of behavior can happen when You want always have one checkbox unchecked. Only this "event.target.checked" magic actually helped tnx much. Another way around would be to actually hide checkbox when it is last unchecked, so user cant do it also.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @JiroMatchonson

Comment: `event.target.checked = false` is a great hack for this. Thanks. I was having an issue keeping a checkbox unchecked when the form is invalid when toggling it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `disabled` on your single checked checkbox:

```
<div class="wrapper" v-for="(s, id) in userOutputSeries" :key="id">
  <input type="checkbox" :id="id" :value="id"
      :disabled="(s.active && numberOfChecked == 1) ? disabled : null"
      @change="preventIfLessThanOneChecked" :checked="s.active">
  <label :for="id">{{ s.display }}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll use the disabled attribute in combination of @thanksd answer to add some extra style too. Your solution is also working. Thanks !